# Why html2text generates HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request?

Tags: macos, command-line, syntax, httpresponse, http-status-code-400

On OS X I've installed `html2text` via Homebrew, however I've got the following error on run:

```
$ html2text http://www.example.com/
```

> HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 349
>
> Connection: close Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 17:21:22 GMT Server: ECSF (iad/18CC)
>
> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`
>
> `****** 400 - Bad Request ******

Although this syntax works:

```
curl http://www.example.com/ | html2text
```

It also works (plain html is returned) when using `curl`, so I'm not sure what XML code is doing when calling URL directly?

What's happening here? Or how do I force fetching HTML using `html2text` command providing the URL directly?

---

This is html2text, version 1.3.2a.

Here is additional info:

```
$ html2text -check http://www.example.com/
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
400 - Bad Request
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 349 Connection: close Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 17:48:20 GMT Server: ECSF (iad/18CD) &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;iso-8859-1&quot;?&gt; 
</P>
<H1>
400 - Bad Request
</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>

$ curl -I http://www.example.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 17:57:56 GMT
Etag: "359670651+gzip"
Expires: Wed, 20 Apr 2016 17:57:56 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT
Server: ECS (iad/182A)
X-Cache: HIT
x-ec-custom-error: 1
Content-Length: 1270

$ curl -0 http://www.example.com/
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    ...  
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    ...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with additional information, the output of: `html2text -version` as well as `html2text -check http://www.example.com/` , thanks

Comment: Great, also: `curl -I http://www.example.com/`, that's an I as in India. thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Now to rule out a protocol issue lets make curl send http 1.0, can you update with what you get from: `curl -0 http://www.example.com/`  , thanks

Comment: @user454038 Updated.